# Rails 4.0.0 Ruby 2.0 therubyracer gem installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, therubyracer

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS precise32 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

I've created Rails (4.0.0) project, uncommented gem 'therubyracer' in Gemfile and run 'bundle install'.

I get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'therubyracer (~> 0.12) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Adding 'execjs', 'libv8' to Gemfile makes no difference as well as uninstalling and installing each of these gems again in all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've specified therubyracer version to 0.12.0 and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Better you can try `bundle update`  it will work.